# Laravel 4 Routing issue

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, url-routing

i hope you can help me out as been scratching my head for ages..

I have the laravel 4 installed in a folder called 'myapp' www.example.com/myapp/

I'm calling this but i'm getting app undefined..

```
Route::get('login', function(){
//do something
});
```

The only way i can get it to work is this way, but it messes everything up all the styles etc..

```
Route::get('/myapp/login', function(){
//do something
});
```

And this is my current .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know how to get it to work just for the myapp folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now figured this out.

I needed to change the .htaccess file from this

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

to this

```
RewriteRule ^ /myapp/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This is the solution if your on shared hosting and do not have access to route, @Mikes comment is the solution if you have access to root.

Answer (score 1):

I think your web server might be misconfigured. A correct web server configuration usually requires no changes to `.htaccess`.

Normally, using Laravel, you should have a `DocumentRoot` directive that points the web server to the public directory of your Laravel installation.

Exactly how you do that varies a little among operating systems. On my system, which is a development system running Ubuntu Linux, and which hosts multiple Laravel projects, I use multiple virtual servers. Ubuntu's configurations for these virtual servers are stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. The configuration file for my calendar project (locally, calendar.dev) looks like this.

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/calendar.dev 
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName calendar.dev
ServerAlias calendar.dev *.calendar.dev
DocumentRoot "/var/www/calendar/public"
HostNameLookups double
</VirtualHost>%
```

If you're using "myapp" in place of the default "public" folder, then your `DocumentRoot` directive should point to "myapp" instead of "public".

If you're using "myapp" in place of the default "app" directory, you need to back up and rethink this. The "app" directory shouldn't be accessible to web users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll keep this in mind. But for this case, i'm on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I agree completely with Mike Sherrill. Laravel ships with **.htaccess** config file that works "out of the box". There was some problems with older Laravel versions, but with L4 no. If you plan to add new virtual host don't forget to register one in **/etc/hosts** file. So check your server configuration.